# String Split with Multiple Delimeters

Tags: java-8

How can I split the string to multiple substrings?

```
String = "5260,GOODS,4,10,TISSUE,,84,\"1,008\",24,24,,,78,84,24";
```

I was spliting the string to string[] by using comma separator ","

```
But One value contains comma - \"1,008\"
```

Is there any way to get the string as

Expected Output -

```
"5260,GOODS,4,10,TISSUE,,84,1008,24,24,,,78,84,24";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to "normalize" your text first by:

**option 1:**
convverting all false positives in other format that skip the split.. i.e. you need to change (maybe with regex) the value 1,008 to something like 1.008

**option 2:**
changing all the "," everyhere for another char(example ":") not present in the string but keeping the value 1,008 and split to ":"